# How to access properties of a linq query in aspx page?

Tags: c#, asp.net, linq, linq-to-objects

I'm returning a list like this from three lists of objects * thanks to @sehe

```
        `var joined = from p in personList
         join par in relations
             on p.Id equals par.PersonId
         join a in addressList
             on a.Id equals par.AddressId
         select new { Person = p, Address = a };`
```

How do I set joined as a datasource for a listview and access the properties in the aspx page?

Okay here's some more code maybe that will help since I'm getting two different answers on this.

// the code behind

```
    protected void Page_Init(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    List<Customer> customers = Customer.GetAllCustomers();
    List<Address> addresses = Address.GetAllAddresses();
    List<AddressRelation> addressRelations = AddressRelation.GetAllAddressRelations();
    var results = from c in customers
                  join rel in addressRelations
                  on c.CustomerID equals rel.CustomerID
                  join a in addresses
                  on rel.CustomerAddressID equals a.CustomerAddressID

                  select new
                  {
                      FirstName = c.FirstName,
                      LastName = c.LastName,
                      PhoneNumber = c.PhoneNumber,
                      AddressLine = a.AddressLine1,
                      CustomerCity = a.City,
                      CustomerZip = a.ZipCode
                  };

    ListView1.DataSource = results;
    ListView1.DataBind();
```

Here's my listview:

```
            `<asp:ListView ID="ListView1" runat="server" >`
            `<LayoutTemplate>`
             <ul style="float:left; width:250px">
             <asp:PlaceHolder ID="itemPlaceHolder" runat="server"></asp:PlaceHolder>
             </ul>
             </LayoutTemplate>
             <ItemTemplate>
             <li><%# Eval("FirstName") %></li>
             <li><%# Eval("AddressLine") %></li>
             </ItemTemplate>
             <ItemSeparatorTemplate><hr /></ItemSeparatorTemplate>
             </asp:ListView>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Two problems here:

You haven't fully enumerated the set yet - you should probably call an aggregator like `.ToList()` or `.ToArray()`.

In addition, you're creating an anonymous object as your result. Outside the specific scope of that code, nothing has any idea what properties that object contains. You should switch to a pre defined class that has known properties if you want to use that object elsewhere.

Comment: ListView takes any collection that implements IEnumerable as a data source. This query implements that, so there is no need to enumerate the query results directly

Comment: I see what you mean. I thought maybe there was a way to cast it to a list and use it like a regular list accessing the anonymous types properties with some magic variable. So what's the point of linq if I can't use it like a regular List? I can print to the console all day long, but I don't see how it's useful in asp.net?

Comment: Doesn't databinding use reflection?  Won't it find whatever properties he's configured his ListView to look for?  People use anonymous types for databinding all the time.  `myComboBox.DataSource = db.TableWith100Columns.Select(x => new { .......}).ToList();

Comment: @Adam - you are correct, it uses reflection so any dynamic object properties are defined in the string used to call Bind() or Eval() in the list view template, and ASP.NET magically finds them (so to speak)

Comment: @Adam So the problem here is my linq statements. They are not returning the query results needed.

Answer (score 3):

You just set the `ListView.DataSource = joined`, and then call `DataBind()` You can access them in your ListView template via `Eval()` or `Bind()` See the [MSDN documentation for the ListView control](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.listview.aspx) for additional examples

Answer (score 1):

To answer the first part of your question, an anonymous type can be used as a data source just like any other type.  ASP.NET will reflect over the source and find whatever properties it needs.

```
myListView.DataSource = joined;
myListView.DataBind();
```

Then, to access these properties in your ListView, just use Bind and Eval.  Here's some [documentation on databinding](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178366.aspx) to get you started

Comment: I'll edit my post to add more code, but I'm not sure who to believe here. Tej's explanation makes since because when I bind, it just silently fails.

Comment: Tej is **WRONG**.  I don't know how he's getting up-voted, but binding to an anonymous object is absolutely ok.  You must have some other problem

Comment: You are calling DataBind(); after you set the dataSource, right?  Just post some more code and I'll take a look

Comment: Yes.. Codes posted. Like I said before, it just silently fails.

Comment: What do you mean silently fails?  Is it possibly your query is returning no results?  If any of your binding expressions were wrong it would fail loudly; you would get a yellow error screen.

Comment: Throw a `int resultsCount = results.Count();` in there, then throw a breakpoint in and make sure your query is returning what you think it is

Comment: I just double checked the results is returning values.

Comment: Okay, I put the count statement in there and set a breakpoint. resultsCount came back 0, but when I hovered over results and checked the inner dropdown it showed a count of 3.

Comment: Wrap your entire query in parenthesis and put a ToList on the end.  I can't imagine what's going on since you're just joining on in-memory Lists, but that won't hurt

Comment: Two other things: you checked the resultsCount *after* the line executed, right?  You didn't just put a breakpoint ON that line and check it when it highlighted in yellow?  Also, please post your entire ListView markup

Comment: I'm guessing the problem is in your ListView.  You might also try binding to a simple GridView with some boundColumns.  If the grid works with the same datasource that fails on your LV, then the problem is in your ListView configuration, which I'm not an expert on.  You'll need to post a new question asking what the problem is with your LV setup.

Comment: @James, when did you *evaluate* the resultCount statement?  You need to make sure the debugger has moved beyond that line before you inspect the value of resultCount.

Comment: I posted the rest of the listview.